# issue with NSDate I am removing year but takes 0001 as year

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Below is my code, and I will explain things in it

```
NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[formater setDateFormat:@"MM-dd"];


NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger desiredComponents = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit);


NSDateComponents *firstComponents = [calendar 
              components:desiredComponents fromDate:fDate];
NSDateComponents *secondComponents = [calendar 
             components:desiredComponents fromDate:eDate];
NSDateComponents *thirdComponents = [calendar 
              components:desiredComponents fromDate:mdate];

NSDate *from = [calendar dateFromComponents:firstComponents];
NSDate *end = [calendar dateFromComponents:secondComponents];
NSDate *middle = [calendar dateFromComponents:thirdComponents];

NSString * froms = [formater stringFromDate:from];
NSLog(@"sringfroms:%@",froms);
NSLog(@"datefrom:%@",from);


NSString * ends = [formater stringFromDate:from];
NSLog(@"sringends:%@",ends);
NSLog(@"dateend:%@",end);

NSString * middles = [formater stringFromDate:from];
NSLog(@"sringmiddles:%@",middles);
NSLog(@"datemiddle:%@",middle);
```

And this is what gets printed.

```
sringfroms:06-30
datefrom:0001-06-29 18:06:32 +0000
sringends:06-30
dateend:0001-08-02 18:06:32 +0000
sringmiddles:06-30
datemiddle:0001-07-14 18:06:32 +0000
```

You can see that i am removing year from date which get printed in string but when i make date it takes 0001 automatically. I am using kal calendar and i want to mark for month and day only so it should get marked for every year

```
if (([middle compare:from] == NSOrderedDescending) 
          &&([middle compare:end] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    [holidays addObject:[Holiday  holidayNamed:naMMe 
                 birthDate:bDate iDs:aIDDS date:middle]];
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: That's just because `NSDate` prints a preformatted string that includes all of that information when you log it.  In reality, `NSDate` is just a `double` containing the number of seconds since a reference time.

Comment: so how can i make my NSDate containing only month and day?

Comment: That request only indicates that you don't understand `NSDate`.  It doesn't care about months, days, years, etc.  **IT IS JUST A NUMBER**.    Only `NSDateFormatter`, `NSCalendar`, etc. care about this sort of stuff.  What is the Kal library expecting?

Comment: if i put date as year month and day in calander then it will be showed only ones but i want that date to get displayed every year at that month and day. thats why want date with only month and day

Comment: I repeat:  *WHAT FUNCTION* of the library are you using and *what type of data* is it expecting?  It might be that you have to manually add it every year.

Comment: parameter is NSdate Fromdate toDate and Middledate

Comment: static BOOL IsDateBetweenInclusive(NSDate *date, NSDate *begin, NSDate *end)
{
  return [date compare:begin] != NSOrderedAscending && [date compare:end] != NSOrderedDescending;
}

Comment: Alright, even after all this discussion this question still makes no sense.  *What* are you trying to do (show the code where you try to "add" to Kal calendar or whatever.  Many of us have probably never used it including myself) and *what* is happening that is wrong (edit your question).  I don't think any of the code in your question is relevant.  It just shows what most of us already know (that `NSDate` will print out a certain way every time).

Answer (score 1):

Its OKAY, since you are not using `NSYearCalendarUnit` in your following code

```
NSInteger desiredComponents = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit);
```

so `NSDate` is assuming `0001` as default year, if you add `NSYearCalendarUnit` in the above code it will give correct year, like below

```
NSInteger desiredComponents = (NSDayCalendarUnit 
                   | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);
```

Comment: i dont want year thats why i am not taking it i want date with only month and day. so it can be displayed every year and not only for one time

Comment: Then why are you worried about year coming as `0001` ?

Comment: if i wasnt worried what i was going to ask here?

Comment: @iphonic please use code tags only for highlighting code. It is not used to highlight general text..

Answer (score 0):

> Well,if you are not mensioned any component then it'l take always
>   first value(01,0001 etc) that is default nature of `NSCalendar`,for resolving your
>   problem you need to convert that date to your date formatt.